# Can there only be one default in a switch in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, switch-statement

I am learning to code games in C++ from "Programming 2D Games" and I have a basic WinMain program shown below however the book says to use two default labels. However my IDE (VS2013) is telling me that a default label has already appeared in the switch.

Is there a way around this issue or have I made a mistake within the switch? I have cross referenced with the book however I can't find any information on this.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h> 
// Function prototypes
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int);
bool CreateMainWindow(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT WINAPI WinProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
// global variable
HINSTANCE hinst;
HDC hdc;                // Handle to device context
TCHAR ch = ' ';         // Character entered
RECT rect;              // Rectangle structure
PAINTSTRUCT ps;         // Used in WM_PAINT
// Constants 
const char CLASS_NAME[] = "Keyboard";
const char APP_TITLE[] = "Character Input";
const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 400;  
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400;
//==================================
// Starting point for the windows application
// Parameters are
// hInstance. Handle to the current instance of the application 
// hPrevInstance. Always NULL, obsolete parameter
// lpCmdLine. Pointer to null-terminated string of command arguements 
// nCmdShow. Specifies how the window is to be shown 
//=================================

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE    hInstance,
    HINSTANCE   hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR       lpCmdLine,
    int         nCmdShow )

{
    MSG msg;
    // Create thw window 
    if (!CreateMainWindow(hInstance, nCmdShow))
        return false;
    // Main message loop 
    int done = 0;
    while (!done)
    {
        // PeekMessage is a non blocking message for Windows messages 
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            // Look for quit message
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                done = 1;
            // Decode and pass messages on to WinProc
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);    

        }

    }
    return msg.wParam;

}

//==============
// Window event callback function 
// ===============================
LRESULT WINAPI WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
        {
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
            //Tell windows to kill this program 
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
    case WM_CHAR:       // A character was entered by the keyboard
        switch (wParam);    // The character is in wParam
        {
        case 0x08:  //Backspace
        case 0x09:  // Tab
        case 0x0A:  // Linefeed
        case 0x0D:  // Carriage return
        case 0x1B:  // Escape
            MessageBeep((UINT) -1);         // Beep but do not display 
            return 0;
        default:            // Displayable character
            ch = (TCHAR) wParam;        // Get the character 
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);   // Force WM_PAINT 
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_PAINT:                  // The window needs to be redrawn 
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps); // Get handle to device context 
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);     // Get the window rectangle
            // Display the character 
            TextOut(hdc, rect.right / 2, rect.bottom / 2, &ch, 1);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            return 0;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
        }


}
//===========================================
// Create the window
// Returns: False on error
//===========================================
bool CreateMainWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcx;
    HWND hwnd;

    // Fill in the window class structure with parameters 
    // That describe the main window 
    wcx.cbSize = sizeof(wcx);               // Size of the structure 
    wcx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;    // Redraw if the size changes 
    wcx.lpfnWndProc = WinProc;              // Points to windows procedure 
    wcx.cbClsExtra = 0;                     // No extra class memory 
    wcx.cbWndExtra = 0;                     // No extra window memory
    wcx.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcx.hIcon = NULL;
    wcx.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);      // Predifined arrow
    // Background brush
    wcx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wcx.lpszMenuName = NULL;    // Name of menu resource 
    wcx.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME; // Name of window class
    wcx.hIconSm = NULL;

    // Register the window class
    // RegisterClassEx return 0 on error
    if (RegisterClassEx(&wcx) == 0) // if error 
        return false;
    // Create Window
    hwnd = CreateWindow(
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Name of window class
        APP_TITLE,                      // Title bar text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style
        CW_USEDEFAULT,                  // Default horizontal postion of window
        CW_USEDEFAULT,                  // Default vertical postion of window
        WINDOW_WIDTH,                   // Width of window 
        WINDOW_HEIGHT,                  // Height of window 
        (HWND) NULL,                    // No parent window 
        (HMENU) NULL,                   // No menu
        hInstance,                      // Handle to application window
        (LPVOID) NULL);                 // No window parameters
    // If there was an error the window
    if (!hwnd)
        return false;
    // Show the window
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    // Send a WM_PAINT message to the window procedure 
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: First, there can't be 2 default case in a switch statement. And second the code you gave is showing the nested switch, so each switch has its own default case, which is alright.

Comment: A few have just helped my understand that, it makes perfect sense now but before I asked it just wasn't clear before.

Comment: Switches w/o braces can bite you. Looks like you're on the right track though. Great to hear someone picking up `C++`, I'm curious how you ended up choosing that? Given the proliferation of higher level languages, it is nice to see people still getting close to the metal.

Comment: I'm going to be studying it at University in September but I can't wait that long to get started with it. I've been interested in it for a while but I'm still a beginner at the moment.

Comment: @PapaSmurf Good question, and I'm glad you asked and got a good answer, and welcome to SO! I encourage you to post only the relevant code to your question in the future, so that people who would answer have an easier time finding the problem ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only have one `default:` per `switch` statement.  But you can put a `switch` statement inside another `switch` statement, and then each can have a `default:` case.

```
switch (var1)
{
    case 1:
    break;
    case 2:
    {
        switch (var2)
        {
            case 1:
            break;
            case 3:
            break;
            default: // var1 is 2, and var2 is not 1 or 3
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
    default: // var1 is not 1 or 2
    break;
}
```

Your code is almost nested `switch` statements like that, but you made one mistake:

```
switch (wParam);    // The character is in wParam
```

should not have the semicolon `;`.  A `switch` applies to one statement immediately after the `)` character, and you almost always want that statement to be a "compound statement" i.e. block surrounded by `{}`.  Instead, this `switch` applies to the do-nothing statement `;`.

Comment: Thanks that was explained very clearly and I now understand my mistake.

Answer (score 7):

You have a typo here:

```
switch (wParam);  // semicolon shouldn't be there
{
    //...
}
```

The semicolon forms the body of the inner switch, and its intended body becomes part of the outer switch. This causes the error, since both contain a `default` branch.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have more than one default statement in a switch. Semantically it would not make sense anyway.

The switch will go through the cases in order looking for a case that matches, and then begin execution from there onward. If a default case is reached, any execution path that remains (has not matched a case) will begin executing from there onward. Any case that would be matched later in the switch will already be executing.

consider the following:

```
char my_case = /*(some value)*/ ;
switch (my_case) {
    case 'a':
        cout << "a case\n";
    case 'b':
        cout << "b case\n";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "DEFAULT\n";
    case 'c':
        cout << "c case";

    default:
        cout << "DEFAULT 2\n";
}
```

for the following values of `my_case` the following output will result:

```
// my_case = a
a case
b case

// my_case = b
b case

// my_case = c
DEFAULT
c case
DEFAULT 2

// my_case = d
DEFAULT
c case
DEFAULT 2
```